# Jstree select_node not working in ver > 3.0.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I need to select a particular tree node during runtime (after assigning Json data) using `$('#mytree').jstree(true).settings.core.data`.

Here is my jquery code:

```
$('#mytree').jstree(true).settings.core.data = mytreedataJson;
            $('#mytree').jstree(true).refresh();
    $("#mytree").jstree("select_node", "1");
```

and also tried

```
$('#mytree').jstree(true).select_node("1");
$.jstree.reference('#mytree').select_node("1");
```

and here is my Json data:

```
var mytreedataJson = [{ "id": "1", "text": "Start Process", "parent": "#" }, { "id": "2", "text": "End Process", "parent": "#" }, { "id": "3", "text": "Next Process", "parent": "1" }];
```

Actually, this code works fine with the jstree version 3.0.0, but not with the greater versions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your code works with async operations - `refresh` will not return immediately. You should probably use:

```
$('#mytree')
    .one("refresh.jstree", function (e, data) {
        data.instance.select_node("1");
    }).jstree(true).refresh();
```